# Flask model return all table columns

Tags: database, postgresql, flask, model, flask-sqlalchemy

i have this on my model

```
class Social(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'social_auth_usersocialauth'
id = db.Column('id',db.Integer, primary_key=True)
provider = db.Column('provider',db.String(32))
extra_data = db.Column('extra_data',db.String())
uid = db.Column('uid',db.String(255))

def __init__(self,id, provider, extra_data, uid):
    self.id = id
    self.provider = provider
    self.extra_data = extra_data
    self.uid = uid
def __repr__(self):
    return self.uid
```

and when i call it to my view, i just get the uid, yes i know because in my model i just returned it's uid, the question is, how can i return all of it's table's columns ?
like id, provider, also extra_data column,,,
Thank you.

Comment: How do you want to display it in the view? Are you using an HTML template e.g.? Please show the complete view code.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way is to comment your **repr** function and return the Social object and use it's attributes by calling

```
social = Social.query.first() # example
id = social.id
providor = object.providor
...
```

But if you really want to do it this way you can return all attributes in **repr** by:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.id, self.providor, self.extra_data, self.uid
```

and changing this in you views to this and get all values by::

```
id, providor, extra_data, uid = Social.query.first() # example
```